# on keyup event of password field validation should perform

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Form validation using jquery
Onkeyup event password input field is verified as minimum 8 character one lower case letter,one upper case letter,one numeric and one special character

Comment: and your question is? your code?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validatePassword() {
    var password = $("#password").val();
    

    if (password.match(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@%!])[0-9a-zA-Z@%!]{8,}$/))
        $("#divPasswordValidationResult").html("pass");
    else
         $("#divPasswordValidationResult").html("fail");
   
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#password").keyup(validatePassword);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="td">
    <input type="password" id="password" />
</div>

    <div class="registrationFormAlert" id="divPasswordValidationResult">
</div>
```

An explanation of regex is :

```
(/^
(?=.*\d)                //should contain at least one digit  
(?=.*[a-z])             //should contain at least one lower case  
(?=.*[A-Z])             //should contain at least one upper case 
(?=.*[@%!])             //should contain at least one of @,%,! (you can add more if needed) 
[0-9a-zA-Z@%!]{8,}         //should contain at least 8 from the mentioned characters  
$/)
```

Answer (score 0):

One example : (take the pieces you like / fit your code)

```
function testPassword(pw) {
    var len = pw.length;
    if(len < 8) return "Too small";
    if(pw.replace(/[a-z]/,'').length > len - 1) return "Need Lowercase Letter";
    if(pw.replace(/[A-Z]/,'').length > len - 1) return "Need Uppercase Letter";
    if(pw.replace(/[0-9]/,'').length > len - 1) return "Need number";
    if(pw.replace(/[!@#$%^&*-]/,'').length > len - 1) return "Need symbol";
    return "GOOD";
}
pw="tessAdfsfdsa9s";
result=testPassword(pw);
if(result=="GOOD"){
    WHATEVER
}
else{
    alert(result);
}
```